# How could Eratosthenes know the angle of the sun's rays in Alexandria?

Tags: astronomy, earth, history

The measurement of the Earth's radius by [Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eratosthenes#Measurement_of_the_Earth's_circumference) is famously the first of its kind. As I understand, it relies on the fact that the sun's rays are parallel. At noon, the light falls directly perpendicular to Earth's surface, which could easily be judged in the original experiment by checking the alignment of shadows in a deep well.

**At the same time in Alexandria**, a city several hundreds of kilometres away, it is not noon, but instead the sunlight falls at an angle from the normal. This angle is enough to calculate the Earth's diameter through some trigonometry.

My question is the following: before standardised clocks and fast communication was invented, how was it possible to tell the exact moment when the angle measurement was to be made? I'm imagining myself in Alexandria with a protractor. **How do I know when it is noon in Syene and when I should make the measurement?**

Comment: He assumed that Alexandria and Syene were on the same meridian, so they had the same local noon. See the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eratosthenes#Measurement_of_the_Earth's_circumference) .

Comment: they only needed to measure the distance between the cities along the plane of solar movement, and use the shadow angle at local noons to have an estimate for the radius

Comment: While this does seem on topic here, you may be interested in [hsm.se] for other historical type queries.

Comment: You already have a good answer, however, that answer doesn't address the following misconception: "At noon, the light falls directly perpendicular to Earth's surface". That's only true in the tropics, and only on one or two days of the year for any given place. This happens on only one day a year (the summer solstice) for a place that is exactly on the Tropic of Capricorn or the Tropic of Cancer, which is very close to where Syene (Aswan) is.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> How do I know when it is noon in Syene and when I should make the measurement?

They didn't need to know *both* the east-west and north-south angles at the two locations, *either* one of those would do.

So they simply measured the north-south angle at local noon in both locations. This is when the sun it at its maximum altitude, an easy measurement.

One can assume the line is close enough to north-south that local noon is the same anyway, or you could easily account for that by subtracting out the east-west difference in the measurement of the distance between the two.

Comment: Aha! So both measure at local noon, but only in Syene this corresponds to actually perpendicular light rays, while in Alexandria the light falls at an angle due to its different latitude. Did I get that correctly?

Comment: @PeterShor [Syene is now called Aswan and is in Egypt.](http://www.wikiwand.com/en/Aswan)

Comment: @ahemmetter - Exactly. Which makes you realize just how smart this guy was, it's not immediately obvious that this would work until you think about how you can eliminate one of the two directions from the measurement.

Comment: I don't see right off how an E-W measurement would work. They are identical at local noon are they not?

Comment: @C.TowneSpringer - indeed, I should have been more clear. If you're on a sphere, any line between two points will do, even and E-W one. But by realizing you only need two points, and they can be oriented anywhere, then picking the N-S line makes life so much easier.